# Trying to understand RSA encryption code example

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to understand this piece of code but I can't get it around my head. 
So the program is taking in a value and using "RSA" algorithm to encrypt it the inputted value.

What I don't understand is the bytesToString part of the code. Is the program converting the inputted values into bytes and then encrypting the bytes?

```
public RSA() {
    r = new Random();
    p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
    q = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
    N = p.multiply(q);

    phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
    e = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength/2, r);

    while (phi.gcd(e).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 && e.compareTo(phi) < 0 ) {
        e.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    d = e.modInverse(phi); 
} 

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    RSA rsa = new RSA();
    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);

    String teststring ;
    System.out.println("Enter the plain text:");
    teststring=in.readLine();
    System.out.println("Encrypting String: " + teststring);
    System.out.println("String in Bytes: " + bytesToString(teststring.getBytes()));

    // encrypt
    byte[] encrypted = rsa.encrypt(teststring.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Encrypted String in Bytes: " + bytesToString(encrypted));


    // decrypt
    byte[] decrypted = rsa.decrypt(encrypted);
    System.out.println("Decrypted String in Bytes: " +  bytesToString(decrypted));

    System.out.println("Decrypted String: " + new String(decrypted));

}
```

You can have a look at the code here from http://www.coders-hub.com/2013/04/implementation-of-rsa-using-java.html?showComment=1426355678160#c2330533116597007284

Also the output of the program looks like this

```
Enter the plain text:
Hello world
Encrypting String: Hello world
String in Bytes: 7210110810811132119111114108100
Encrypted String in Bytes: 0-91-1-63245736-287660-6518-312926-102125-106-899450-8765-100100-126-1810592-123-65-26-104-96-894689-9746-1225763-1-94-43-3498-19-101-45-607227-69-79115-94-43-28-10123-7258-16-413-1854-51-24-11925-100-582056-89121-16-6010512239-1111188570-73-80-591-432-23-94-105-10311672381-76-28-1021-38-51-67-32122-2-10-51-86-15-37-104-5721100-84-444085-126-61-5011554-39-15-18-126-685-48-25-25124-11541-108-1846107112-104-9-56-101-90121582574-18-74-954184-80-6856-97-6797-23202-125-724833-19-26-934637-127-126-327399-834924-116-44-53-13-7526-8041104-4093123102101-95-2462-1684-8841119119-10581-9011178-83-521858-2321-570-107-10-54-708-981076-17-9934103-19-3943-11974-2365-1202630117-107-123-2411-47-624119-78
Decrypted String in Bytes: 7210110810811132119111114108100
Decrypted String: Hello world
```

Is any of that the public key or the private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the program converting the inputted values into bytes and then encrypting the bytes?

Yes, encryption is usually performed on binary data. The RSA primitive on the other hand uses modular arithmetic on big integers. The `RSA` that you showed uses `BigInteger` internally which provides a [constructor `BigInteger(byte[] val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte[]%29) to create a big integer out of a byte array.

There is another [constructor `BigInteger(String val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a string, but it is assumed that the String simply contains the number to be encrypted in base 10 notation and not arbitrary data.

> Is any of that the public key or the private key?

No, none of those values is a representation of the public or private key. The key pair is hidden away behind `RSA rsa = new RSA();`.

The public key is made up of the modulus `N` and the public exponent `e`. The private key is made up of the modulus `N` and the private exponent `d`. Oftentimes the private key also contains the public exponent to make it possible to create the public key from the private key.

Optimized implementations have other intermediate values in the private key which your implementation doesn't use.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Have you had a look at the full code? should i be printing e for the public and d for the private key?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but don't use this for actual encryption in a project. This is raw RSA which is really broken. It isn't optimized and doesn't use padding. Use the [`Cipher` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) instead.